# C++ Getting the Name of a Process via ProcessID

Tags: python, c++, winapi, process, win32gui

For example from the PID 10948 I would like to get the process name of firefox.exe

I've tried using `GetModuleFileNameEx`, `GetModuleFileName`, `GetProcessImageFileName`, and `GetModuleBaseName` and all of them result in a garbage string of characters such as:  `╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ 7Σ`

My code:

```
DWORD* thread = new DWORD;
TCHAR szName[_MAX_FNAME];
HANDLE processhandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), thread));
GetProcessImageFileName(processhandle, szName, _MAX_FNAME);
strrchr(szName, '\\');
```

Originally I tried doing this using python using the win32gui library using the process's handle, which worked, but it would not be able to find command prompt handles. I don't care which language I use to solve this problem of identifying the current program being in use as long as I am able to find the name of all programs that I can possibly use.

Comment: I'd start with checking for errors on the function calls. If the first call fails the second is useless.

Comment: This works, so I'm guessing OpenProcess is failing. https://ideone.com/O0GW65

Comment: How can I check if OpenProcess is failing?

Comment: Perhaps the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`OpenProcess()` returns `NULL` if it fails. Call `GetLastError()` to find out why. Same with `GetProcessImageFileName()`.

Also, try using `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` instead, as it requires fewer rights.

Also, you should zero out your `szName` buffer before filling it.

Also, you don't need to use `new` to allocate a `DWORD` for `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`.

Try this:

```
DWORD threadid;
DWORD processid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), &threadid);
HANDLE processhandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, processid);
if (!processhandle) {
    // handle error as needed...
}
else {
    TCHAR szName[_MAX_FNAME] = {};
    if (!GetProcessImageFileName(processhandle, szName, _MAX_FNAME)) {
        // handle error as needed...
    }
    // ...
    CloseHandle(processhandle);
}
```

Comment: *Also, you should zero out your szName buffer before filling it* - this is out only parameter. we of course can, but not need do this. and even if want do this (which is really not need) can for example set 1 zero - `*szName=0` only

Comment: @RbMm my point is, `GetProcessImageFileName` doesn't zero out the buffer, so if it fails, you end up with garbage if you don't zero it yourself and then ignore the return value, like the OP was originally doing.

Comment: need check returned value, like in your code, and if fail, simply not use it.